# Qualtrics- Constant Sum

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I have a few question that I've programmed using "Constant Sum". However, by default, a "0" appears when the questions pops up. Rather than "0" showing when the question appear, I would like it to be blank instead. The respondent will then click on it and enter "0" when they are entering the count/when the count stands true as "0". Any advice or guidance is greatly appreciated! Thank-you!!

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: You'll have to write a JavaScript to change to zeros to empty strings.

Comment: Even then, you will struggle to have them manually update a constant sum. YOu would be better off using multi-line text entry, restricting entry to numbers, and writing a function to automatically update the last row when other rows are updated.